# WSGI Django 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

When I run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I get an error

```
unable to resolve host hostname
```

When I look at the error.txt it says it's my WSGI configuration.

Here is my WSGI script.

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
import django



os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
sys.executable = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
application = WSGIHandler()

django.setup()
```

**EDIT1:**

Here is my apache2 file. I did change the WSGI file to /user/app/app_settings/wsgi.py

```
    <VirtualHost website:80>
   ServerName website.com
   ServerAlias www.website.com
   ServerAdmin email@website.com

   DocumentRoot /home/user/app/static

   WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/app/app_settings/wsgi.py
   <Directory /home/user/app/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   #Alias /robots.txt /var/www/user/app/robots.txt
   #Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/user/app/favicon.ico
   #Alias /images /home/user/app/static/images
   #Alias /static /home/user/app/static/

   ErrorLog /var/www/website/error.log
   #CustomLog /var/www/website/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And what is the Apache configuration you added? Also, why aren't you using the ``wsgi.py`` file that Django generated for you? There are multiple things wrong with your WSGI script file.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Hey, I just added the apache file that is in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. I apologize it is my first time deploying a working website, and the tutorial I was given is outdated. I changed the directory to the wsgi.py file and restarted apache2 however now I'm getting a 500 service and no error in the error.log

Comment: For a start, where you have ``<VirtualHost website:80>`` it should be ``<VirtualHost *:80>``. The hostname you use for the site would be then what you have set with ``ServerName``. That hostname must be resolvable, so have a DNS entry which maps to the IP of the host, or you must have an entry in local ``/etc/hosts`` for it if do not have it in DNS.

Comment: You have a list of other things wrong, but at least see if you can get Apache responding for you first.

Comment: Do I have to have the django directory in /var/www/mysite directory or can it be set in a /home/user directory? Also the reason that I have a <VirtualHost website:80> is because i have more than one domain being hosted.

Comment: Also because you found the 403 error can you post the wsgi script file in django and I'll accept it?

Comment: If you put stuff under ``/home/xxx``, then default permissions of home directories usually means that user Apache runs your code as cannot access it. Better not to have under home directory.

Comment: It should be ``<VirtualHost *:80>``. It is ``ServerName`` and ``ServerAlias`` which Apache matches on for host. The bit before ``:80`` is only used when wanting to restrict listening for connections to certain network interfaces, which is unlikely want you want and would have needed to be an IP address anyway. Set it to ``*:80`` if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: hey I got it all fixed @GrahamDumpleton could you post the answer to change the path in apache2.conf to the wsgi.py in django app and I'll accept it.